# Making fields visible only in ListView

Tags: security, permissions, account, sharing

I am having a hard time accomplishing this. My requirement is to have Account object private but i need few fields from accounts to be visible in the account list view for all users such as Account Name, Owner and Contact. 
I set the org wide default for Account to private, but i am not able to set field level security on Account to read only.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Once you allow users to see certain fields, they will be able to see them in list views and also in record view. Security permissions apply to the object, not to the view itself. You can remove fields from layouts to hide them visually from the users. Try using permission sets or profiles to give field-level access to certain fields.

Comment: If you're interested in using Field Level Security, there is some info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_admin_intermediate/data_security/data_security_fields

Answer (score 0):

Setting an object to Private makes those records visible only to record owners and those above them in the role hierarchy unless Grant Access Using Hierarchies checkbox set to disable so if you want to share your record with **all the users** you need to set org as Public Read Only

**Public Read Only**

- All users can view and report on records but not edit them. Only the owner, and users above that role in the hierarchy, can edit those records.

  For example, Sara is the owner of ABC Corp. Sara is also in the role Western Sales, reporting to Carol, who is in the role of VP of Western Region Sales. Sara and Carol have full read/write access to ABC Corp. Tom (another Western Sales Rep) can also view and report on ABC Corp, but cannot edit it.

if you want to hide some specific fields from specific user you can remove field level security for that profile.

Comment: That makes sense, however, I want certain fields hidden only from the accounts that person Does not own. 
I still need those fields visible/editable to that person when they create a new account and on the accounts they already own.